# SAP BO - how to get 1/0 distinct values per week in each row

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, business-objects

the problem I am trying to solve is having a SAP Business Objects query calculate a variable for me because calculating it in a large Excel file crashes the process.

I am having a bunch of columns with daily/weekly data. I would like to get a "1" for the first instance of Name/Person/Certain Identificator within a single week and "0" for all the rest.

So for example if item "Glass" was sold 5 times in week 4 in this variable/column first sale will get "1" and next 4 sales will get "0". This will allow me to have the number of distinct items being sold in a particular week.

I am aware there are Count and Count distinct functions in Business Objects, however I would prefer to have this 1/0 system for the entire raw table of data because I am using it as a source for a whole dashboard and there are lots of metrics where distinct will be part/slicer for.

The way I doing it previously is with Excel formula:
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A5000=$A2)*($G$2:$G5000=$G2))>1,0,1)

This does the trick and gives a "1" for the first instance of value in column G appearing in certain value range in column A (column A is the week) and gives "0" when the same value reappears for the same week value in column A. It will give "1" again when the week value change.

Since it is comparing 2 cells in each row for the entire columns of data as the data gets bigger this tends to crash.

I was so far unable to emulate this in Business Objects and I think I exhausted my abilities and googling.

Could anyone share their two cents on this please?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an object in the query that uniquely identifies a row, you can do this in a couple of simple steps.

Let's assume your query contains the following objects:

```
Sale ID
Name
Person
Sale Date
Week #
Price
etc.
```

You want to show a 1 for the first occurrence of each Name/Week #.

Step 1: Create a variable with the following definition.  Let's call it `[FirstOne]`

`=Min([Sale ID]) In ([Name];[Week #])`

Step 2: In the report block, add a column with the following formula:

```
=If [FirstOne] = [Sale ID] Then 1 Else 0
```

This should produce a 1 in the row that represents the first occurrence of Name within a Week #.  If you then wanted to show a 1 one the first occurrence of Name/Person/Week #, you could just modify the [FirstOne] variable accordingly:

`=Min([Sale ID]) In ([Name];[Person];[Week #])`

Comment: Joe, this worked. Thank you so much.
What kind of bugged me - my formula has far less distincts than your BO solution. 
I checked it and it seems yours is accurate and formula is not. 

Thanks a bunch for a great clean and quic solution. 
Big thanks to Gordon too for chiming in and giving good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want logic around `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when 1 = row_number() over (partition by name, person, week, identifier
                                         order by ??
                                        )
             then 1 else 0
         end) as new_indicator
from t;
```

Note the `??`.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no "first" row in a table or group of rows, unless a column specifies that ordering.  The `??` is for such a column (perhaps a date/time column, perhaps an id).

If you only want one row to be marked, you can put anything there, such as `order by (select null)` or `order by week`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!